# Templated element-wise comparison function for containers

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to write a templated element-wise comparison function for containers as follows:

```
struct identity {
  template <typename U>
  constexpr auto operator()(U&& v) const noexcept
      -> decltype(std::forward<U>(v)) {
    return std::forward<U>(v);
  }
};

template <typename Comparator, typename Container>
constexpr auto elem_compare(const Container& a, const Container& b) noexcept {
  Container elemCompare{a};
  std::transform(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), b.cbegin(), elemCompare.begin(),
                 Comparator{});
  return std::all_of(elemCompare.cbegin(), elemCompare.cend(), identity{});
}
```

When trying to use this as in

```
  std::array a{-0.3, 0.1, -0.5};
  std::array b{0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
  auto isLessEqual = elem_compare<std::less_equal>(a, b);
```

I get a compiler error telling me that template argument deduction/substitution failed.

What do I have to do to make the compiler deduce the template arguments to `elem_compare` correctly?

---

Edit: would this be a better implementation? How could I further improve it?

```
template <template <typename> typename Comparator, typename Container>
constexpr bool elem_compare(
    const Container& a,
    const Container& b,
    const Comparator<typename Container::value_type>& comparator =
        Comparator<typename Container::value_type>{}) noexcept {
  auto a_iterator = std::cbegin(a);
  auto b_iterator = std::cbegin(b);
  for (; a_iterator != a.cend() && b_iterator != b.cend();
       ++a_iterator, ++b_iterator) {
    if (!comparator(*a_iterator, *b_iterator))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: `std::less_equal` is a type template, not a type. `typename Comparator` expects a type. But even if you fix that, your implementation has some major problems (can't handle types that can't be converted to `bool` and back, creates a temporary container for no good reason, can't handle containers of different size, can't work with stateful comparators).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! Since I'm doing this for educational purposes, I'll try to find a way to improve the implementation and address the shortcomings you pointed out.